# Getting a null value in the phno variable outside the Movie_genre constructor

Tags: java, constructor

After calling the `Movie_genre` class I still get a `null` value in the phno variable outside the parameterised constructor `Movie_genre`.

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

```
    phno=jTextField1.getText();
    String p1=new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
    String p2="";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/show_booking","root","123456");
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String query="Select Password from login where Phone_no='"+phno+"';";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            p2=rs.getString("Password");
        }
        if(p1.equals(p2))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Login successful");
            Movie_genre obj1=new Movie_genre(phno);
            Movie_genre obj=new Movie_genre();
            obj.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here's the Movie_genre class.

```
     public Movie_genre(String phno)
{
    phno1=phno;
    System.out.println(phno1+"sidhflf");
}
public Movie_genre() 
{
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println(phno1);
    Action obj1=new Action(phno1);
    Action obj=new Action();
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted the *complete* code for `Movie_genre`, and we have no context for the other code fragment which might help us figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: 1. Is phno=jTextField1.getText(); getting a valid string? 2. I think you may neee to post Movie_genre class.

Comment: That's the part of the code which was causing problems. But if you have any questions regarding the code you can ask, cause the entire code is unnecessary I believe.

Comment: yes I initialized phno at the very beginning.

Comment: That's all the coding that I've done rest all is generated by NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

```
  phno=jTextField1.getText().toString();
    String p1=new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
    String p2="";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/show_booking","root","123456");
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String query="Select Password from login where Phone_no='"+phno+"';";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            p2=rs.getString("Password");
        }
        if(p1.equals(p2))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Login successful");
            Movie_genre obj1=new Movie_genre(phno);
            Movie_genre obj=new Movie_genre();
            obj.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: your can try this     phno=jTextField1.getText().toString();

Comment: I get the null value in the Movie_genre class not this one.

Comment: public Movie_genre(String phno)
{
   this. phno1=phno;
    System.out.println(phno1+"sidhflf");
} use this